# array.index (of: ) not working properly

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, indexing

I'm trying to find a UITableViewCell text in an array. The problem is no matter what cell I'm clicking on, `array.index(of:)` always returns 1.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let text = cell.textLabel?.text {
        let indexOfCellString = event.index(of: text)
        print (indexOfCellString!)
    }

}
//here is my attempt to set the cell text:
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if eventIndex.indices.contains(indexPath.row) == true {
    cell.textLabel?.text = event [indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

event is an array that i'm trying to search in and find cell's text. 
and cell's text is always in an index of event. because my tableview reads the information from event array. therefore it shouldn't always return 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No one can help you without more information. You have not explained what `event` is. You haven't provided any details about what `text` contains. The code you posted isn't valid. What is the `self)` line?

Comment: it should return the index of event that cell.textlable.text is in.
but no matter which table row i tap on, it always returns 1. 
needless to say that table rows have different strings in them

Comment: Where's your attempt to set the cell's label's text?

Comment: i edited the question and added my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`. Simply access your data from your data model.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if eventIndex.indices.contains(indexPath.row) == true {
        let text = event[indexPath.row]
        if let indexOfCellString = event.index(of: text) {
            print("Found index: \(indexOfCellString)")
        } else {
            print("text not found")
        }
    }
}
```